# How to tell whether any smtp server like postfix, ssmtp is already installed on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: mail, smtp, moodle

I have moodle 3.1 set up on Ubuntu 16.04 minimal version. Moodle is unable to send any email and errors are pointing to smtp configuration.

The mail notifications from moodle worked by default in dev server.
But in production with same setups and configuration mail notifications are failing.

My Dev server is local vm and prod is in aws.

I need to check whether any smtp package like postfix is already installed in aws Ubuntu 16.04 image

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
aptitude search '~Pmail-transport-agent' | grep "^i"
```

will return the following if there is no package installed which provides a proper mail transport agent

```
i   lsb-invalid-mta                 - Linux Standard Base sendmail dummy
```

ie if you run

```
aptitude search '~Pmail-transport-agent'
```

you will get every package that is eventually capable of sending emails. In case of Ubuntu 16.04 that is

```
p   citadel-mta                - complete and feature-rich groupware server (mail transport agent)
p   citadel-mta:i386           - complete and feature-rich groupware server (mail transport agent)
p   courier-mta                - Courier mail server - ESMTP daemon
p   courier-mta:i386           - Courier mail server - ESMTP daemon
p   dma                        - lightweight mail transport agent
p   dma:i386                   - lightweight mail transport agent
p   esmtp-run                  - user configurable relay-only MTA - the regular MTA
p   exim4-daemon-heavy         - Exim MTA (v4) daemon with extended features, including exiscan-acl
p   exim4-daemon-heavy:i386    - Exim MTA (v4) daemon with extended features, including exiscan-acl
p   exim4-daemon-light         - lightweight Exim MTA (v4) daemon
p   exim4-daemon-light:i386    - lightweight Exim MTA (v4) daemon
i   lsb-invalid-mta            - Linux Standard Base sendmail dummy
p   masqmail                   - mail transport agent for intermittently connected hosts
p   masqmail:i386              - mail transport agent for intermittently connected hosts
p   msmtp-mta                  - light SMTP client with support for server profiles - the regular MTA
p   nullmailer                 - simple relay-only mail transport agent
p   nullmailer:i386            - simple relay-only mail transport agent
p   opensmtpd                  - secure, reliable, lean, and easy-to configure SMTP server
p   opensmtpd:i386             - secure, reliable, lean, and easy-to configure SMTP server
p   postfix                    - High-performance mail transport agent
p   postfix:i386               - High-performance mail transport agent
p   qmail-run                  - sets up qmail as mail-transfer-agent
p   sendmail-bin               - powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Transport Agent
p   sendmail-bin:i386          - powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Transport Agent
p   ssmtp                      - extremely simple MTA to get mail off the system to a mail hub
p   ssmtp:i386                 - extremely simple MTA to get mail off the system to a mail hub
```

Answer (score 0):

For something easier to type and remember, all MTAs that I know of (including Postfix, sSMTP, and exim, in addition to Sendmail itself) install a `sendmail` executable and a corresponding manual page. Thus, if one of those is installed, `man sendmail` will open a manual page which will also tell you which one it is.